# Groovy select NodeChild from array of known nodes

Tags: xml, groovy

I have an array of possible node names and I need to iterate through the array and if the node.text() is not null or empty then it appends that to a string to build an XML string.

I am parsing an Excel spreadsheet and each row is turned into a record, each record is then parsed by XmlSlurper().parseText()

My issue is that I can not get it to pull the text using currentNode.val.text(), currentNode."${val}".text(), but it will pull the text by using currentNode.node1.text().

```
    allFields = ["node1","node2","node3"]

    NodeChild currentNode = it

    for (int z=0; z<allFields.size; z++){

       val = allFields[z[.toString()

       if (currentNode.val.text() == null || currentNode.val.text() ==""){
           do something
       }
       else{
            do something else
       }
   }
```

Comment: Maybe post some actual code you've tried? The above code has errors

Answer (score 0):

`currentNode.val.text()` will pull the node `val`.  You could just search for your node:

```
def xmlText = '''\
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
<node1>some 1</node1>
<node2>some 2</node2>
<node3></node3>
<node4>some 4</node4>
<node5>some 5</node5>
</root>'''
def xml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xmlText)
def whitelist = ['node1', 'node3']
xml.'**'.findAll{ it.name() in whitelist }.each{
        if (!it.text()) {
                println 'Emtpy'
        } else {
                println "Hit: ${it.text()}"
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I went with this option after trying to fix mine over and over.